# how to resolve jitsi ConnectionService in API level 33 in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, jitsi

```
<application
           <service
        android:name="org.jitsi.meet.sdk.ConnectionService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.telecom.ConnectionService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
```

**I am adding in my android manifest but launcher(splash) screen black**

Comment: do you solve this error

Comment: Yes, I was custom complete sdk ..